# Bundled Typescript Compiler API

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I am using the [typescript-json-schema](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema) to inspect interfaces at runtime. Due to some other dependencies I am required to bundle my code in the end using webpack, after bundling the code does not work anymore and it fails to find the typescript types.

After some investigation I figured the issue is related to the typescript compiler API. Without bundling the code below outputs all the type files found in node_modules including the typescript ones, after bundling it still finds all but not the typescript ones.

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
export async function main() {
    const p = ts.createProgram({
        rootNames: ["src/dummy.ts"], options: {}
    });
    p.getSourceFiles().forEach(s => console.log(s.fileName));
    console.log(p.getSourceFiles().length);
}
```

Am I missing something or is bundling the typescript not supported?

---

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV == "development" ? "development" : "production";

module.exports = {
    mode,
    entry: "./src/app.ts",
    target: "node",
    devtool: mode === "development" ? "source-map" : undefined,
    node: {
        global: true
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "bin"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        libraryExport: 'default'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: "ts-loader",
                test: /\.tsx?$/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES6",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "bin",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "bin/**/*.ts",
        "build/*.ts",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
}
```

---

Edit: Adding the output
**Before Webpack**

```
project/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts
project/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
project/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.d.ts
<ommitted...>
src/dummy.ts
project/node_modules/@types/json-schema/index.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/async_hooks.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/buffer.d.ts
<ommitted...>
```

**After Webpack**

```
src/dummy.ts
project/node_modules/@types/json-schema/index.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/async_hooks.d.ts
project/node_modules/@types/node/buffer.d.ts
<ommitted...>
```

Comment: `I am using the typescript-json-schema to inspect interfaces at runtime.` may I ask why? It sounds like you may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Kyll We need to verify that TS interfaces match JSON configs on our backend. Neither the interface nor the config is known at compile time. So we want to generate a schema from the interface and compare it against the config.

Apart from being a potential XY problem I would still like to know why the bundling changes the behavior. :)

Comment: @surrz I haven't looked into this but I'm almost certain that it has something to do with inference based on member names or export names that are being mangled.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's what I don't quite get, neither the interface nor the type files are bundled. After webpack, TS is still able to find the json-schema, node and lodash types but **not** the ts types such as Record or Map.

Comment: @surrz based on your edit, that's what we would expect. Those files aren't part of your project. It's up to the consumer to provide those files. That would be the same when in development however.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, but I would expect the result to be the same after and before webpack.